# Problems with routing the default identity pages in an ASP.NET Core with Razor app

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm having trouble with login in ASP.NET Core 3.0 app.

Essentially, I want the login page to be at

```
mywebsite.com/login
```

instead of

```
mywebsite.com/SomerandomRoute/SomeMore/WhyNot/MakeTheUrl/EvenLonger/Identity/Cookies/DefaultIdentity/Pages/Sections/Defaults/Identity/LoginRouteController
```

as is the default. So I added `@page "/login"` to the identity login `.cshtml` file, and it works when clicking "log in" in the top nav.

Thing is, with that alone, redirecting from protected pages doesn't work. As in, if I'm not logged in and go to the account settings URL, I get redirected to the long abomination of an URL instead of `/login`. And that route doesn't exist now.

In my 2.2 app I could just

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
    });
```

and it would work, but in this 3.0 app it breaks login completely. Submitting the login form just redirects to index and the user isn't logged in.

I tried looking for breaking changes between 2.2 and 3.0, but nothing seems to say anything about my particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/login";
    });
```

is what was needed.